# WARNING: The script pip3.8 is installed in '/usr/local/bin' which is not on PATH

Tags: python, pip, path, centos, centos7

When running `pip3.8` i get the following warning appearing in my terminal

```bash
WARNING: The script pip3.8 is installed in '/usr/local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pip-21.1.1 setuptools-56.0.0
WARNING: Running pip as root will break packages and permissions. You should install packages reliably by using venv: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
```

How to solve this problem on centos 7?

Comment: A similar question to this can be found on the server fault forum: https://serverfault.com/questions/102932/adding-a-directory-to-path-in-centos

Comment: After installing logout or restart system work for me.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This question has been answered on the serverfaults forum: Here is a [link to the question](https://serverfault.com/questions/102932/adding-a-directory-to-path-in-centos).

You need to add the following line to your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` file.

```sh
 export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

You will then need to profile, do this by either running the command:

```sh
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Or by simply closing your terminal and opening a new session. You should continue to check your `PATH` to make sure it includes the path.

```sh
echo $PATH
```

Comment: Missing a colon after bin?

Comment: Well spotted @NorwegianClassic

Answer (score 19):

The other answers will work, but I found a more idiomatic way to do it on an AWS fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.

That path statement is already there, but in .profile

You'll need to log out, and log back in. Sourcing the environment won't do it.

REASON:

In .profile, the code:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

will execute and automatically add .local/bin to your Path, when you log on.

If you install pip3 via `sudo apt install python3-pip` that directory JUST got created, and you haven't logged out yet - and so that path statement hasn't executed.

You could also execute .profile after doing the `sudo apt install`.

Answer (score 0):

**For those using MAC-OS**

Just in case you get warnings like:

```
The script normalizer is installed in '[Python/*version*/bin]' which is not on PATH
```

You can run:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:[Python/*version*/bin]"
```

This question was discussed in [the-script-is-installed-in-directory-which-is-not-path](https://superuser.com/questions/1372793/the-script-is-installed-in-directory-which-is-not-path) and [adding-a-directory-to-path-in-centos](https://serverfault.com/questions/102932/adding-a-directory-to-path-in-centos)
but this solution is more specific to using PIP3 install [package].

Answer (score 0):

Just RUN

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:[Python/*version*/bin]"
```

In terminal and thats it