# Python3 command not calling Python3.8

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 Instance. I want Python3.8 on the server so I installed it but it gets installed in `/usr/local/bin`. So I tried to add it to the path following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70588185/warning-the-script-pip3-8-is-installed-in-usr-local-bin-which-is-not-on-path) then also I am not being able to get Python3.8 when python3 is called instead it goes for Python3.7 which is default in the machine. How to solve this?

Comment: You can run `which python3` to see where it is getting run. It's probably a symbolic link to the executable, which you can replace.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with `update-alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python3.8`

This should be enough if your system uses python 3 as a default version (to check that type `python --version`)