# Error while installing hyfetch through pip on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: installation, terminal, pip, ubuntu-20.04

I can't get hyfetch to work, and when i tried reinstalling it this warning showed up:

```
WARNING: The script hyfetch is installed in '/home/twankle/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

how do i fix this?

i tried uninstalling and reinstalling because im not sure what to do
i have python3.8 which is enough for hyfetch
the method im installing it with is

```
pip install hyfetch
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+WARNING%3A+The+script+is+installed+not+on+PATH.

Comment: Esp. this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73256004/7976758